# How to create a classified image based on the results of classification of Sentinel-2 channels in R

Tags: r, geospatial

I built the classifier that separates wheat and mustard(other), where the predictors are 12 Sentinel-2 channels.

Example data

```
cla=structure(list(geom_id = c(6790546L, 6790550L, 6790555L, 6790559L, 
6790562L, 6790563L, 6790564L, 6790590L, 6790600L, 6790601L, 6790606L, 
6790622L, 6790625L, 6790626L, 6790637L, 6790642L, 6790646L, 6790655L, 
6790671L, 6790675L, 6790679L, 6790683L, 6790686L, 6790688L, 6790692L, 
6790694L, 6790695L, 6790697L, 6790700L, 6790710L, 6790717L, 6790720L, 
6790722L, 6790729L, 6790731L, 6790734L, 6790735L, 6790740L, 6790743L, 
6790749L, 6790751L, 6790760L, 6790768L, 6790772L, 6790773L, 6790774L, 
6790779L, 6790800L, 6790801L, 6790803L, 6790807L, 6790808L, 6790813L, 
6790833L, 6790834L, 6790837L, 6790838L, 6790841L, 6790843L, 6790845L, 
6790853L, 6790856L, 6790860L, 6790865L, 6790867L, 6790872L, 6790878L, 
6790883L, 6790884L, 6790885L, 6790886L, 6790890L, 6790893L, 6790894L, 
6790896L, 6790909L, 6790910L, 6790917L, 6790919L, 6790921L, 6790922L, 
6790933L, 6790934L, 6790937L, 6790940L, 6790944L, 6790945L, 6790947L, 
6790950L, 6790953L, 6790959L, 6790960L, 6790962L, 6790963L, 6790964L, 
6790965L, 6790966L, 6790967L, 6790968L, 6790970L, 6790971L, 6790978L, 
6790979L, 6790984L, 6790985L, 6790986L, 6790992L, 6790993L, 6791001L, 
6791007L, 6791013L, 6791024L, 6791028L, 6791033L, 6791035L, 6791036L, 
6791038L, 6791041L, 6791051L, 6791052L, 6791053L, 6791056L, 6791058L, 
6791068L, 6791070L, 6791094L, 6791095L, 6791101L, 6791102L, 6791103L, 
6791106L, 6791108L, 6791111L, 6791117L, 6791121L, 6791124L, 6791130L, 
6791131L, 6791132L, 6791139L, 6791140L, 6791158L, 6791160L, 6791161L, 
6791169L, 6791174L, 6791185L, 6791187L, 6791188L, 6791191L, 6791195L, 
6791204L, 6791210L, 6791212L, 6791214L, 6791220L, 6791222L, 6791225L, 
6791236L, 6791240L, 6791243L, 6791248L, 6791249L, 6791255L, 6791259L, 
6791262L, 6791269L, 6791270L, 6791277L, 6791288L, 6791291L, 6791293L, 
6791296L, 6791297L, 6791304L, 6791321L, 6791336L, 6791337L, 6791342L, 
6791344L, 6791345L, 6791347L, 6791350L, 6791357L, 6791365L, 6791368L, 
6791371L, 6791380L, 6791386L, 6791391L, 6791393L, 6791404L, 6791407L, 
6791418L), lon = c(75.599167, 75.599167, 75.599167, 75.556982, 
75.556145, 75.599167, 75.556137, 75.985352, 75.658261, 75.662465, 
75.600357, 75.636266, 75.636266, 75.838797, 75.841827, 75.575345, 
75.609937, 75.592098, 75.61778, 75.53143, 75.513269, 75.44303, 
75.848044, 75.366963, 75.48927, 75.503759, 75.503759, 75.85975, 
75.85975, 75.707679, 75.707679, 75.646203, 75.646405, 75.647233, 
75.580001, 75.580923, 75.580455, 75.580001, 75.580832, 75.631573, 
75.3782, 75.622802, 75.453422, 75.980249, 75.980249, 75.980249, 
75.972825, 75.91223, 75.921534, 75.44303, 75.612564, 75.661273, 
75.725387, 75.898045, 75.674384, 75.674381, 75.6759, 75.667174, 
75.674381, 75.66572, 75.531472, 75.531441, 75.665277, 75.579813, 
75.579738, 75.516323, 75.674365, 75.499946, 75.623393, 75.623393, 
75.625719, 75.625719, 75.629793, 75.63081, 75.63081, 75.579912, 
75.579912, 75.580031, 75.676323, 75.671537, 75.676323, 75.644082, 
75.655357, 75.643368, 75.643368, 75.754415, 75.755253, 75.748308, 
75.674385, 75.621704, 75.671537, 75.675973, 75.671537, 75.671537, 
75.671537, 75.675973, 75.671537, 75.675973, 75.671537, 75.671537, 
75.671537, 75.671537, 75.66572, 75.671537, 75.671537, 75.671537, 
75.599428, 76.171439, 75.549103, 75.502447, 75.68989, 75.617839, 
75.617778, 75.701654, 75.697399, 75.610906, 75.689917, 75.721703, 
75.716614, 75.716614, 75.597703, 75.721703, 75.75572, 75.738865, 
75.738865, 75.678035, 75.678035, 75.328565, 75.328117, 75.3248, 
75.32199, 75.303827, 75.221108, 75.286941, 75.260181, 75.211361, 
75.273309, 75.278092, 75.277616, 75.315888, 75.31924, 75.861897, 
75.89514, 75.900852, 75.893882, 75.925349, 75.717955, 75.962328, 
75.966927, 76.006322, 75.984966, 75.57405, 75.499082, 75.510588, 
75.536081, 76.16435, 75.551609, 75.579165, 75.762403, 75.508313, 
75.749362, 75.760105, 75.730494, 75.985691, 75.984363, 75.994228, 
75.973333, 75.734407, 75.972652, 75.923356, 75.907053, 75.290386, 
75.990112, 75.872672, 75.559077, 75.642815, 75.428548, 75.491017, 
75.298945, 75.526391, 75.324213, 75.2917, 75.308238, 75.515889, 
75.699041, 75.683968, 75.6402, 75.601958, 75.585805, 75.62428, 
75.3061, 75.778848, 75.74013, 75.718297), lat = c(26.198987, 
26.198987, 26.198987, 26.241533, 26.241587, 26.198987, 26.241594, 
26.22464, 26.204939, 26.199725, 26.207977, 26.122947, 26.122947, 
25.906995, 26.086256, 26.098898, 26.300308, 26.294742, 26.310587, 
26.121792, 26.131689, 26.228846, 26.067021, 26.106764, 26.190292, 
26.138985, 26.138985, 26.06696, 26.06696, 26.121733, 26.121733, 
26.35865, 26.363045, 26.392034, 26.095477, 26.095782, 26.095643, 
26.095477, 26.095743, 26.427993, 26.275007, 26.356205, 26.234503, 
25.954103, 25.954103, 25.954103, 25.98859, 26.034662, 26.05662, 
26.228846, 26.226848, 26.271675, 26.263878, 26.106967, 26.126528, 
26.126427, 26.119369, 26.128602, 26.126427, 26.128093, 26.12192, 
26.121828, 26.199375, 26.095475, 26.095477, 26.115205, 26.127163, 
26.109492, 26.023783, 26.023783, 26.021817, 26.021817, 26.021463, 
26.020164, 26.020164, 26.095253, 26.095253, 26.095492, 26.132527, 
26.123624, 26.132527, 26.260792, 26.247978, 26.265658, 26.265658, 
26.125818, 26.127218, 26.12619, 26.27022, 26.112256, 26.123624, 
26.126413, 26.123624, 26.123624, 26.123624, 26.126413, 26.123624, 
26.126413, 26.123624, 26.123624, 26.123624, 26.123624, 26.128093, 
26.123624, 26.123624, 26.123624, 26.307803, 25.898768, 26.180855, 
26.110799, 26.286696, 26.008663, 26.008207, 26.071474, 26.071713, 
26.02648, 26.072052, 26.076292, 26.069277, 26.069277, 26.027133, 
26.076292, 26.125875, 26.195207, 26.195207, 26.325735, 26.325735, 
26.439247, 26.440721, 26.406755, 26.426792, 26.555275, 26.512878, 
26.542467, 26.52223, 26.514869, 26.497046, 26.514049, 26.503029, 
26.497252, 26.450875, 26.133693, 26.101302, 26.11167, 26.111185, 
26.115355, 26.24128, 25.92573, 25.923008, 25.990642, 26.02366, 
26.328851, 26.465209, 26.456277, 26.217762, 25.906022, 26.179428, 
26.176192, 26.024658, 26.15243, 26.031555, 26.026417, 25.989288, 
25.944507, 25.960935, 25.955333, 25.971988, 26.127123, 25.95761, 
25.879238, 25.884732, 26.543827, 25.942485, 25.898077, 26.137837, 
26.019097, 26.203658, 26.181645, 26.23862, 26.43428, 26.403855, 
26.412433, 26.44636, 26.450063, 26.244547, 26.245935, 26.35466, 
26.215152, 26.216695, 26.207403, 26.5411, 26.102281, 26.065263, 
25.985928), crop = c("Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Wheat", "Wheat", "Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", "Wheat", "Other", 
"Other", "Wheat", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Wheat", "Wheat", 
"Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Wheat", 
"Other", "Wheat", "Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", 
"Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", "Wheat", 
"Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other"
), pred = c("Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Wheat", 
"Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Wheat", 
"Wheat", "Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", 
"Wheat", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Wheat", "Wheat", "Other", 
"Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", 
"Wheat", "Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Wheat", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Wheat", "Other", "Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-194L))
```

I used this article as a basis for my work and here is an example of visualization
https://isprs-archives.copernicus.org/articles/XLII-5/683/2018/isprs-archives-XLII-5-683-2018.pdf

There
[image]

However, unfortunately, this article does not indicate how using R, these classification results can also be visualized on a map.

So I'm looking for information: How to use R, which libraries can I use for this, maybe `ggplot2` or another.
I would be glad to get any help.
Thank you.

Comment: As you have `terra`  and the original sentinal raster that you further modeled, here is a [process overview-sentnal2 10km resolution - resample](https://www.pmassicotte.com/posts/2022-04-28-changing-spatial-resolution-of-a-raster-with-terra/) cla_rast = terra::rast(cla), resample cla_rast to original sentinal2 to get its characteristics (resolution, crs etc), plot(cla_rast).